# php Maximum size upload not validating properly

Tags: php

```
if(!empty($employeepic)) {
    if ((($employeepic_type == 'image/jpg') ||($employeepic_type == 'image/jpeg') ||($employeepic_type == 'image/gif') ||
         ($employeepic_type == 'image/png')) && ($employeepic_size <= EMP_MAXSIZE) && ($employeepic_size > 0)){
        // Move the file to the target upload folder
        $target = (EMP_UPLOADPATH .$firstname.$employeepic);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['employeepic']['tmp_name'],$target)){
            $employee = $firstname. " " .$lastname;
        }
    }else{
        $filetoobig =' <p class="error"> There was a problem uploading your picture. Maximum size is 30K and must be in jpg, jpeg or pjpeg format</p>';
        @unlink($_FILES['employeepic']['tmp_name']);
    }
}
```

Can anyone see why the validation of file size not working?

```
(EMP_MAXSIZE = 32768)
```

**Edit:** The limit size is set at 32768 but can still upload 2MB files

**Edit:** The code to assign `Employee_pic` Size:

```
$employeepic = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_FILES['employeepic']['name']));
$employeepic_type = $_FILES['employeepic']['type'];
$employeepic_size = $_FILES['employeepic']['size'];
```

Comment: Where do you set `$employeepic_size`?

Comment: How is it failing? Is it rejecting files that are under the limit, or is it allowing files that are over the limit?

Comment: You don't need to delete the temporary file, PHP will automatically do that when the script finishes.

Comment: I can upload files that are bigger than the 32768 limit. I can upload files that are 2MB in size.

Comment: have you tried echoing `$employeepic_size` to see what it is?

Comment: yes I have tried echoing EMP_MAXSIZE and also the size of the file itself.  Both are echoing correctly in size:
EMP_MAXSIZE =32768
picture file uploaded =2000000

Comment: Please paste your code assigning the value to $employeepic_size

Comment: Check carefully for typos in the variables.

Comment: What does `var_dump($employeepic_size <= EMP_MAXSIZE)` say?

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `mysqli_real_escape_string` when creating a filename. That should only be used to escape data to be stored in the database. And it would be better if you used a prepared query instead of string substitution.

Comment: Barmar - dump_var say = bool(false) after I try to upload a larger than MAXsize

Comment: BARMAR - I am saving to mysql actually.  this is where the problem happen.  If validation turns false I should not be able to save the file to mysql nor in the folder where I store the file itself.  When I upload below the MAXSIZE I (true) returned to me. if I go over the MAXSIZE I get a (false) at it should but what I don't get is why am I saving the file still in myaql and in the folder even if the result is false.  Would the problem be in my query itself?

Comment: UPDATE: I don't know what just happened(I haven't changed any code) but now the file is not being saved to folder when over the limit size of 32768.  But still the name of the file gets saved to mysql.  Maybe I should point out that I am using dreamweaver 2014.  I have noticed a few irregularities from time to time. can this be a Dreamweaver problem?

Comment: Couple of things 1) you dont need to delete the tmp file, PHP does that when script ends. 2) You say it is still getting save to the database!! **Where is the code that does that** Does it check the file size before doing the database update???

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I am probably not doing the "right way of coding" but it nevertheless fixed the problem.  I created another variable called $employee_pic = $firstname.$employeepic; in the true section of my validation and added "employee_pic='' ;" under the false result of my validation in order not to save the picture to mysql. This was accomplished by changing the $employeepic variable for $employee_pic in my insert query.